# PHP: Select from mysql where 1 week's left to datetime?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a datetime field in MYSQL database.

They look like this:

```
2017-02-28 00:15:07
```

I need to select and return all the results from this field that has 1 week let to that date using PHP...

Is there any built in PHP feature to do this?

something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 1 week left to (column name)
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by `1 week left to`? 1 week prior to that date?

Comment: @chris85, yes. correct.

Comment: Like this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e388fc/1 ... or it needs to be in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use interval like the following:

```
SELECT *  FROM tableName 
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN (column_date - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND column_date;
```

That will let you know if **now** is between the `column date - 1 week` and the `column date`.

Comment: Great deal with SQL Fun

Answer (score 0):

Could be using date_sub and date_create_from_date_string

this is for php

```
date_sub($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("7 days"));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php

for a select query

```
select *  FROM tableName 
WHERE your_column_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 week) AND NOW();
```

Comment: how do you use this in a select query?